# next.js: how to define an sitemap.xml route with server-side-rendered content?

Tags: next.js, vercel

We are trying to add a `/sitemap.xml` to our (mostly) statically generated next.js/Vercel page.

While there are many tutorials and many different solutions, I would prefer the least "invasive" approach inside the next.js platform.

Generating the `sitemap.xml` during the build process seems odd to me, as the page infrastructure already provides SSG /Static Site Generation to do things at build-time. The problem with such a standard SSG "page" is that I would need hardcoded routes in the `_document` so that it renders no page skeletion for the sitemap, which seems unintuitive and error-prone.

The other option that crossed my mind, a custom `/pages/api/sitemap` endpoint with a [redirect](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) from `/sitemap.xml` to that location, also seems wrong, since the `/pages/api` doesn't seem to permit SSG (which is understandable in the context of an API but would here cause unnecessary server load).

Are there any other options?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the reasoning being not using the API route. The response will be generated on the server when accessing that route. Is it the case that you want to only generate the sitemap at build-time instead?

Comment: @juliomalves, yes, that is correct, all routes are static, so I would prefer a fully static sitemap.xml as well

Comment: Why don't you store it in the public folder?

Comment: @Gh05d, counterquestion, why do I have to "store" it instead of "generating" it like the pages themselves?

Comment: You can do both. Write a script which generates a sitemap at build time and saves it in public folder. I mean, you can do it as a route I guess, but it is highly unusual.